# Angular directive link attrs

Tags: angularjs

I was going through the Angular documentation and had a question about directives. This is in regards to the "Creating a Directive that Manipulates the DOM" section of http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

I added some console.log() statements in the following code:

```
scope.$watch(attrs.myCurrentTime, function(value) {
  format = value;
  updateTime();
});
```

like so:

```
scope.$watch(attrs.myCurrentTime, function(value) {
  console.log('attrs.myCurrentTime = ', attrs.myCurrentTime);
  console.log('value = ', value);
  format = value;
  updateTime();
});
```

When changing the contents of the 'Date format' text box, I was expecting to see the same value in both console.log() statements, namely the actual value of the parent scope's format attribute, but the first console.log() still shows 'format' as a string.

Why do you think this might be?

Link to code: http://plnkr.co/edit/8LkKBiIpqTn0gr5fXQZL?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, there is no parent scope. Since your directive does not declare a scope (either isolate or "normal") there is no scope created, so the element shares the same scope as its parent-element.

<sub>A quick and easy way to check the scope of an element using DevTools is this:

 1. Select the element in the "Elements" panel.

 2. In the console, execute the command: `angular.element($0).scope();`</sub>

---

So, what is actually going on ?

`attrs.myCurrentTime` represents a plain old string value (namely "format").
So `console.log('attrs.myCurrentTime = ', attrs.myCurrentTime);` is equivalent to `console.log('attrs.myCurrentTime = ', 'format');`

In the same way, `scope.$watch(attrs.myCurrentTime, ...)` is equivalent to `scope.$watch('format', ...)`.
According to the **[docs on Scope](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope)**, if the first argument of `$watch` is a string it is *"evaluated as **[expression](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)**"*, which in this case means as `scope['format']` (which of course returns the current value of the scope's `format` property).

Comment: This is an excellent overview of what is going on and makes perfect sense. Thank you!